# Orchard CMS. Problems trying to implement my own ILogger and ILoggerFactory

Tags: asp.net, logging, log4net, orchardcms

I'm trying to implement my own version of ILogger which will log orchard errors. This should override the current null logger that Orchard is using.

I have created my implementation. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225040/how-orchard-cms-does-the-logging) I have created an implementation of ILoggerFactory which returns my implementation of ILogger.

```
public ILogger CreateLogger(Type type)
{
    return new LoggerService();
}
```

I have also registered the ILoggerFactory and the ILogger:

```
builder.RegisterType<LoggerFactory>()
       .As<ILoggerFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<LoggerService>()
       .As<ILogger>().InstancePerDependency();
```

And suppressed the dependency:

```
[OrchardSuppressDependency("Orchard.Logging.LoggingModule")]
```

However my logger service is not hit at any point.

Any suggestions welcome!

---

Additionally, it seems both autofac registration modules are being hit implying that LoggingModule is not being suppressed.

---

There is a patch submitted to solve this problem here: https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18037

However it is unclear as to the status of the item.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question but this could save you some time. From the accepted answer on the question you linked to, Piotr said: 'The NullLogger is just a placeholder so accessing the property would not throw NullReferenceExceptions before the property is being set by Autofac.' - Orchard actually uses log4net which is configured from `Orchard.Web\Config\log4net.config` (you can see it referenced in the appSettings section in the root web.config) - is it not possible to configure log4net to do what you need instead of implementing your own logging?

Comment: @mdm Unfortunately not. I have a separate service that handles logging for the rest of the solution and that's the one that needs to be used for all logs (Orchard and Solution).

Comment: The point @mdm is making is that you're probably looking in the wrong place for the extensibility point. What you should do is implement an appender for Log4Net, not an ILogger for Orchard.

Comment: I have an implementation of the log4net service but this is part of another component which is exposed by an interface in the orchard solution. This is what I would need to call with the ILogger implementation if possible.